# jQuery UI Autosuggest not working when scrolling through selections and hitting the enter key to select

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete. I am facing some issues.

When scrolling through autosuggest in the populated list and hitting the enter key to
select, its not firing the event "select". I am setting a hidden field with the value that is selected. This works fine if i select the item using the mouse.

```
$(autoSuggestField).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../Transport/location",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "prefix": request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.Name,
                            x: item.Code
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(codeField).val(ui.item.x);
//sets the value to hidden field.

        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me (I'm using a different datasource, but `select` fires whether I use the mouse or keyboard): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/7nBZK/

Comment: its working fine for me. actually this happened due to some mistake that i did. I made it working with out changing the abouve code. Thanks. by the way, how will i close this thread?